# Force www. and SSL without choosing ports

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

How do I force www. and SSL on my server

my current code is shown below...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.sitename\.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sitename.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I try this in my .htaccess file I get "This webpage has a redirect loop" can anybody think of a suggestion whilst maintaining the users requested URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try just:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.sitename\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sitename.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This still happens to cause the error and allows the user to access the http version of the site :/

Comment: This causes a Redirect Loop